# detecting browser with asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In normal asp.net the following works:

```
   private float getInternetExplorerVersion()
{
  // Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
  // (indicating the use of another browser).
  float rv = -1;
  System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
  if (browser.Browser == "IE")
    rv = (float)(browser.MajorVersion + browser.MinorVersion);
  return rv;
}
```

but in asp.net mvc2 gives error at "System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;":

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase' to 'System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities'

Thanks
Arnab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the [Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.browser.aspx) property is of type [`HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilitiesbase.aspx) instead of [`HttpBrowserCapabilities`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.aspx). So either use implicit `var` or specify the proper type:

```
float rv = -1;
var browser = Request.Browser;
if (browser.Browser == "IE")
    rv = (float)(browser.MajorVersion + browser.MinorVersion);
```

or if you prefer typing lots of code:

```
float rv = -1;
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase browser = Request.Browser;
if (browser.Browser == "IE")
    rv = (float)(browser.MajorVersion + browser.MinorVersion);
```